# Ubuntu Space issue

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am facing an issue with Ubuntu server.I am running php script using cron job which executes after every 5 minutes which is basically updating mysql table. This folder spool/mqueue is showing 112GB space. How can we reduce the space & what might be the reason of this change?

Comment: @BlackHatShadow: This question is perfectly on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

That folder is for mail queue. Run command 'mailq' to see what is in queue. If it's full of spam, you can do some cleanup. If those mails should be sent, you have to find out why your sendmail (or whatever is in use) is not working properly.

mailq might need sudo rights to run.

Answer (score 0):

The mqueue folder is where emails are stored.  cron jobs will send an email to the user running the cron job with any output from the job.

If you do not need this, then you can tell cron not to send email:

```
crontab -e
```

Then insert before the php job:

```
MAILTO=""
```